# Proxy with express and laravel

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, express, proxy

I'm trying to create a proxy with my nodejs app (express) to my laravel app. I'm using the express-http-proxy module so I tried using this function:

```js
app.use("/w", proxy("localhost:8081", {
  https: false,
}));
```

but when I try to access the page http://localhost:8080/w an error appears

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:8081
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1195:16)
```

Does anyone know how to solve it because I can't find anyone who has solved the request rejection with laravel

Comment: I'm assuming your laravel app is running on 8081 and you tried accessing `http://localhost:8081` in your browser and it works?

Comment: When I access `http://localhost:8081` it works, but what I would like to do is access `http://localhost:8080/w` (reading laravel).

Comment: What's your setup like? Is this in a container or VM or something like that?

Comment: I am now using ubuntu based, on my personal PC, I don't use docker, VM or anything else

Comment: Do you have a proxy set up at `npm` level? Are you in a corporate network? It looks like the `localhost` is not resolved. check `npm config ls -l` and `env` variables. If nothing is similar with a proxy you can also try to pass the IP `127.0.0.1` in place of `localhost`

Comment: I don't know why, but it worked with the numeric IP address, thank you very much.